# Best way to disable default "tooltip" on a dojo / dijit toolbar icon?

Tags: javascript, dojo, tooltip, label, toolbar

Given this code snippet:

```
<div id="divDrawingToolbar" data-dojo-type="dijit/Toolbar">
    <button id="btnMyTestButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'putYourIconCssHere',showLabel:false">point</button>
        <span id="btnMyTestButton_tt" dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="btnMyTestButton">I only want this tooltip displayed. I want to disable the small yellow default 'point' tooltip below.</span>
</div>
```

My custom tooltip displays fine, but I want the little yellow default "point" tooltip (see pic below) to be displayed. Sometimes depending on the size/placement of the custom tooltip, the default tooltip will even partially hide it. If I change showLabel:false to showLabel:true, this gets rid of the tooltip, but I then of course have the full text being displayed next to the toolbar icon, which I do not want. If I leave showLabel set to false, but just delete the point text from the button (), then my point placement functionality breaks on the map. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing but we're new to dojo and I'm currently out of ideas. Any help is appreciated.
[image]

---

*** Update *** - I found an approach which gives the desired result and seems to work, but it's very hacky. Basically, change the "< button >" code from:

```
<button id="btnMyTestButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'putYourIconCssHere',showLabel:false">point</button>
```

to

```
<button id="btnMyTestButton" onmouseover="javascript:document.getElementById(this.id).title = '';" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'putYourIconCssHere',showLabel:false">point</button>
```

I'm thinking there has to be a more "proper" way of accomplishing this...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Dojo are you using? You are mixing legacy and modern Dojo syntax. And what sort of iconClass is 'putYourIconCssHere'? Your code and your question seem a bit muddled to me.

Adding a link to the complete list of Dojo iconClasses: http://amagard.x10.mx/dojo_icon_classes.html (if you don't want to define your own icon css)

Comment: Thanks Leta for the reply. I put the 'putYourIconCssHere' there as a heads up. We're using a custom .css and image for our toolbar, so i knew it would blow up if someone copied/pasted the code as is - here is what the original icon code looked like: `data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitDrawingIcon dijitDrawingIconPoint', showLabel:false"`

Comment: "mixing legacy and modern" - yes im afraid this might be - in short as i said we are very new to Dojo...this is probably due to us using "sample" snippets (possibly from articles of diff. ages). So as for my specific question...when we set "showLabel:true", we see the text with the icon, when "showLabel:false", we get the look that we want, but the yellow tooltip ("Point") pops up automatically it seems. Is our modern/legacy dojo code mixture causing this behavior? What specifically do i need to change in my code to stop the "Point" tooltip form displaying? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I should clarify that above, when I say we used our own custom .css/images, we actually started with the "Dijit" drawing icon that we got from an example, and then modified the .PNG graphic to reflect our own custom icons. Also forgot to add - thanks for the icon classes reference - very handy!

Comment: Which version of dojo are you loading? What require lines are you loading and in what order? With that, we can get a jsfiddle working. FYI, article on Modern Dojo vs. Legacy: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modern_dojo/